# HTML code for audio using PCRE

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

I have a function to use audio in an HTML file

```
function html_code_for_audio($audio_file_location)
{
   $extension=strtolower(substr(strrchr($audio_file_location, '.')  ,1));
   $html_code=
    '<audio controls> '.
    '<source src="'.$audio_file_location.'" type="audio/'.$extension.'" >'.
    'Your navigator is not well equipped to display audio files</audio>';
   return($html_code);
}
```

and I wonder if this code snippet can be improved/shortened using PCRE functions ; something like :

```
$html_code=
preg_replace('`(.+)\.(.+)`', 
'<audio controls> '.
'<source src="$1.$2" type="audio/$2">'.
'Your navigator is not well equipped to display audio files</audio>'
, $audio_file_location);
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Note that the MIME type for `.mp3` is `audio/mpeg`, NOT `audio/mp3`. Your code is wrong as it is.